# How do we pronounce the camera company name "Canon"?

Tags: pronunciation

How do we say Canon - the camera company name? Is it Keh-nun or Keh-non?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe it's pronounced like "cannon". As in a cannon that shoots cannonballs. Here's an [example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ppXT-jANmYM) of its usage.

Comment: +1 Based on their ads in my country, it has always been pronounced the same as "cannon".

Comment: Absolutely, it is pronounced like the clergyman, the body of work and so on as defined by [the Oxford online dictionary](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/canon) which also gives a pronunciation. I've always thought that the company was named to imply strict adherence to standards.

Answer (score 1):

It's usually pronounced the same as the English word "canon", i.e. /ˈkanən/.

Canon is a Japanese company, and their name in Japanese is pronounced *kiyanon*, but they seem to prefer the English pronunciation in their advertising, even in Japan.

Comment: Do you mean that the name is a Japanese word pronounced _kiyanon_ that just happens to look like an English word when transliterated?

Comment: Maybe helpful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canon_Inc.#Name